# python requests cannot get the content but js-like thing

Tags: python-requests

I run the script below to get text from the pages

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for number in range(30700,30000,-1):
    url='http://www.cuyoo.com/article-'+str(number)+'-1.html'
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    en=soup.find(id='en')
```

but some time later, it cannot parse any text.

Using IDM to download any page in the range, it turned out to be something like javescript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">function m5Bg(m5Bg_){function _m(m5Bg_){function af0(){return getName();}function m5Bg_(){}return af0();return m5Bg_}; return _m(m5Bg_);}AYHl=function(){'AYHl';var _A=function(){return 'tic'}; return _A();};_ddD3V = 'href';_Pm641 = location;_hvT79 = window;function Mkv9(){'return Mkv9';return 'gn='}function C7(C7_){function _C(C7_){function d(){return getName();}function C7_(){}return d();return C7_}; return _C(C7_);}function i7(){'i7';function _i(){return '_'}; return _i();}tzWe=function(){'return tzWe';return 'htm';};RGR=function(RGR_){'return RGR';return RGR_;};function L7(){'return L7';return '1'}_DpS4o = 'assign';function xg(){'return xg';return '-'}function y5(){'y5';function _y(){return '.'}; return _y();}function CZ(){'return CZ';return '1'}lsSS=function(){'return lsSS';return 'dc9';};KdU9='/ar';function getName(){var caller=getName.caller;if(caller.name){return caller.name} var str=caller.toString().replace(/[\s]*/g,"");var name=str.match(/^function([^\(]+?)\(/);if(name && name[1]){return name[1];} else {return '';}}_EFvNj = 'replace';location[_DpS4o](KdU9+AYHl()+(function(){'return MiqN';return (function(){return 'le-';})();})()+(function(){'return rZLT';return (function(){return '307';})();})()+'91'+xg()+L7()+y5()+tzWe()+(function(d9R_){'return d9R';return d9R_})('l?')+i7()+C7('b9')+RGR('si')+Mkv9()+lsSS()+CZ()+(function(){'return XC';return (function(){return '5';})();})()+m5Bg('Dks9'));_hvT79.href=KdU9+AYHl()+(function(){'return MiqN';return (function(){return 'le-';})();})()+(function(){'return rZLT';return (function(){return '307';})();})()+'91'+xg()+L7()+y5();</script>
```

Then I open the page in Chrome, the url turned to be followed by "?_dsign=*"

How to deal with the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, what are you trying to get?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham "en=soup.find(id='en')" is what I want to get.  The problem is I can get the content at first, but about 200 times later things change.

Comment: @goldmonkey its likely to be some kind of browser challenge, like a captcha, you could try reverse-engineering the javascript to see what the function does and try to replicate that in requests, it may set a cookie, or trigger another HTTP request to prove you are human.